# What event does IE dispatch when an activex control is being unloaded?

Tags: activex

Hi I have a ActiveX like this:

```
class CMyActiveX :
   public CComObjectRootEx...
   ...
{
   HRESULT FinalContruct(){return S_OK;}
   void Start()
   {
      // a new thread is created here for some task
   }
   void FinalRelease()
   {
      // if the thread is alive kill it
   }
}
```

However when browser is closed the method FinalRelease is not called. So the thread keeps alive and a crash is encountered at the exit.

Any idea on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my control::SetClientSite(NULL) was reliably called by IE when closing or leaving the page, so I do my crucial shutdown stuff there.
It's an override of a method in IOleObjectImpl.

```
HRESULT CControl::SetClientSite(IOleClientSite *pClientSite)
{
    if (!pClientSite) {
        // Means IE is closing or about to, or at least
        // that we've lost our place in the sun...
        do shutdown stuff
    }
    IOleObjectImpl::SetClientSite(pClientSite);
    if (pClientSite) {
        ....
```

[MSDN - IOleObject::SetClientSite method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)